# How to check installation and version using command line for any package?

Tags: linux, command-line, package

Like I want to check python version, I will do:

```
python -V
```

but for checking nltk version, `nltk -V` will not work. I have to do:

`python -c "import nltk; print nltk.__version__"`

Is there any generalized way to check whether particular **package or library** `x` is installed or not, if installed then getting version number for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lesmana said there is no standard way. You can try several different options but still it does not guarantee success:

```
import module_name

version = getattr(module, 'VERSION',
    getattr(module, 'version',
        getattr(module, '__version__', None)
```

With something like this, maybe even better looking, you can try the most common variants: VERSION, version, **version**, **VERSION**.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no generalized way to check whether particular package or library x is installed or not, or to get the version number for the same. You have to research how for each package or library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip installed, you can use

```
pip freeze
```

This lists all the packages installed with its version. If you don't have pip installed, you should.